# Why isn't my boost::multi_index modify() compiling?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm using `boost::multi_index_container` and am trying to get a `modify` operation working.  My modification routine looks like this (roughly), using a function inner class:

```
void FooContainer::modifyAttribute(string key, int newValue) {
    struct ModifyFunc {
        int val;
        ModifyFunc(int val): val(val) {}
        void operator()(Foo &f) {
            foo.val = val;
        }
    };
    StorageContainer::index<keyTag>::type &idx = mContainer.get<keyTag>();
    StorageContainer::index<keyTag>::type::iterator iter = idx.find(key);
    idx.modify(iter, ModifyFunc(newValue));
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get a multi-page spew of compiler error like this (most of it omitted):

```
FooContainer.cpp:##: error: no matching function for call to [...]::modify([...]&, FooContainer::modifyAttribute(string,int)::ModifyFunc)’
```

What's wrong with this invocation and how can I make it work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does the error-message change if you declare `operator()` as `const`?

Comment: Nope. The problem is that the function inner class is being used as a template argument, which is invalid, but the compiler wasn't figuring out the name resolution well enough to provide a meaningful error message. I'd figured this out myself before posting (thus the self-answered question) but I figured it was an obscure enough chain of issues that I should post here in case someone else is puzzled by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that function inner classes aren't recognized by the compiler as a valid typename for template parameters; it isn't obvious, but the `multi_index_container::index<T>::type::modify` method uses the type of the modify parameter as a template argument which is a detail normally hidden from view.  However, look at its declaration in, for example, `boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp`:

```
template<typename Modifier>
bool modify(iterator position,Modifier mod)
```

The easy fix is to make the `ModifyFunc` struct not a function inner class; trivially, make it inner to `FooContainer` rather than to the `FooContainer::modifyAttribute` method.  Of course, this also means that you can reuse the `ModifyFunc` class elsewhere, if it turns out you need it in more than one place.

Comment: And just as a slight rant, it would have been nice if boost had instead defined Modifier as an abstract base class that had modify() take it as a const reference instead (although that would have added const requirements to modify() which would have a potential impact on some obscure use cases).